# How to override contact us from in shopify?

Tags: forms, shopify

I am new to Shopify and I want to create feedback form and for that, I would needed base of the contact form. Now the thing is how to override contact us form.

Answer (score 0):

There would be template suffix of contact form page in the online store > Pages.

Comment: but i dont want to change original file of contact form

Comment: okay then you can make a copy/backup of the original contact form and then use it.

Comment: There are two forms, contact and feedback. If I made changes in contact, feedback form will be changed too. I want to make them separate

Comment: Just do a thing, it might be useful, just as I said, copy the template of form which you want to use and name it with different notation and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Theme Editor and create a new page template and give it a name of your choice. Now open your contact page's admin screen and simply change the page template to the one you created.